# Friendsystem on PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, social-network-friendship

at this moment I'm stucked on my code.

I want to display the names of **accepted** friends.

I have two tables:

```
Users 
[id, useruniqueid, username]

Friends
[id, user_a, user_b, status]
```

*(status can be requested, pending or accepted)*

For example:

```
Users:
1, 123, Kaan2106
2, 321, SOUser1
3, 456, SOU2
4, 654, Some4

Friends:
1, 123, 321, accepted
2, 321, 123, accepted
3, 456, 123, accepted
4, 123, 456, accepted
5, 654, 123, pending
6, 123, 654, requested
```

I want to display my friend(s) names like: "SOUser1" (because it's accepted)

And this is what I done:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
</tr>
<?php
$getem = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Friends WHERE (`status` = 'accepted') AND (`user_a` = '$UserUUID' OR `user_b` = '$UserUUID') LIMIT 10");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getem)) {
    $friendsql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE useruniqueid = '" . ($row['user_a'] == $UserUUID ? $row['user_b'] : $row['user_a']) . "'");
    $friendrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($friendsql);
?>
<tr>
    <td class="friend-name">
        <?php echo $friendrow['username']; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

And my output is like this `SOUser1, SOUser1, SOU2, SOU2`
(unwanted doubles)

The expected output should be like this `SOUser1, SOU2`
(no doubles)

I know that mysql_* is deprecated

Comment: ....recoding's not much fun.

Comment: *"I know that mysql_* is deprecated"* - So, why use it? You're probably just going to end up recoding everything and having done all the work for nothing. Why don't you do things right and right away, and use mysqli or PDO and with a prepared statement.

Comment: so.... back to your code/question. So, what's not working the way you'd want it to? You said you have an output; so what's the "expected" output? You never posted a question, per se. Edit: [This is a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358600/lets-send-new-users-off-to-see-the-wizard#comment526922_358600) in a [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358600/1415724) that was created for posts just like this.

Comment: Use a `join` and this will be easier. Also don't use `*` when not needed, only select the columns you need.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I added the expected output.
It should be like "SOUser1, SOU2" (no doubles)
(Later when I update to PHP7 I want to recode everything)

Comment: Use a `join` and either `distinct`, or `group` the results by username.

Comment: @chris85 I will edit the `*` in my code asap - thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do it all in one query (with a `join`), you can use MySQL's `distinct` operator to only return one instance of each user's name.

Try using a query like the one below. The join uses a case statement so that it joins the Friends table by either user_a or user_b, depending on which one is *not* the `$UserUUID`.

```
select distinct
    u.username
from
    Friends f
    join Users u
        on (
            u.useruniqueid = case
                                when f.user_a='{$UserUUID}' then f.user_b
                                else f.user_a
                            end
            )
where
    (f.user_a = '{$UserUUID}' or f.user_b = '{$UserUUID}')
    and f.status='accepted'
```

See it in an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2a25c/3), with `$UserUUID` being set to '123'.

Comment: Wow... thats amazing, thanks @RToyota
This is a bit too complex _on the first view_ but it works like a charm.

Accepted answer and thank you for your help :)

I have to learn more about that :p.

Comment: @Kaan2106 Haha, it's not too complex; it's just verbose. If you break it down, it just joins the two tables in the usual way (eg: `select * from t1 join t2 on (t1.id=t2.id)`). The only difference is that I've added a case statement to determine which column to join Friends on. The join will either happen as `on (u.useruniqueid=f.user_a)` or `on (u.useruniqueid=f.user_b)`. The `case` statement just acts as a regular case statement (aka like an `if` statement) to make sure it uses the correct user_a or user_b to join in the correct `Users` row (ie not the`$UserUUID`).

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. Now I come closer to the code.